# Why does printing from an uninitialised array crash my computer?

Tags: arrays, c++11, stdio

I'm running cygwin on windows 10. I was messing around with some C++ and ran this code a bunch of times. My laptop turned unresponsive, and after a few seconds, I got a bluescreen and had to reboot. The thing is, all I'm doing is reading from memory and printing to stdout, which shouldn't cause this. I checked, and the array size doesn't exceed the max stack size for cygwin.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (){
    double a[6675];
    int i = 0;
    while (i<6675){
        printf("%f\n", a[i]);
        ++i;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The bluescreen does not violate the C++ standard, but it certainly does look like a bug somewhere. Though the standard doesn't define the behavior, there should be no bit pattern in a `double` object that would cause `printf` to blow up that way. (BTW, I can't reproduce the problem on my own Windows 10 system with Cygwin).

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behaviour<sup>(1)</sup> and literally *anything* is allowed to happen, up to and including the early heat death of the universe.

Granted it's very unusual for the actual computer to blue-screen so you may want to consider the possibility that it's unrelated (unless you can replicate it of course).

But, as mentioned, don't do UB. There's a reason why the first word is "undefined" :-)

---

<sup>(1)</sup> As one example, floating point values are allowed to have trap bits, meaning that dereferencing arbitrary uninitialised variables may actually result in UB.

Short of trolling through the standard, there *may* be other cases where UB comes out of your given code. I just don't have the inclination to do that for code which should probably never see the light of day :-)

But, in any case, even if it *weren't* UB, it's still a bad idea, since you may well just print out a lot of arbitrary floating point values.

Comment: Thanks! I've replicated it once, and my computer is pretty stable otherwise, so I'm pretty sure it's not unrelated. Yeah, I know it's undefined behaviour. Guess I'll just give up on trying to decipher why it happens and leave it at that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is UB as it is reading uninitialized local variables.

Comment: Also, yeah this is literally me messing with the compiler and seeing what it does with really dumb code, not intended for use in anything whatsoever.

Comment: Definitely UB, no doubt about it. `a` is an object with automatic storage duration, and therefore it has an indeterminate value unless and until it is initialized. Attempting to evaluate an indeterminate value is explicitly undefined behavior in both C++11 and later versions of the standard. (C++11 talks about it in terms of lvalue-to-rvalue conversions, if I remember correctly, which is particularly obtuse. C++14 made the wording much clearer. But the implication is identical in both cases.) That said, you're right that a modern protected-memory OS should *not* blue-screen here.